# How can I list the number of files/directories

Tags: c, unix

I wrote this function that actually lists the contents of a given directory. However, I want to make it just tell me how many files and how many directories there are. I've tried things like this, but it doesn't really work:

```
if(dir->d_type == D_DIR)
   directories++;
```

Here's my code. How can I modify it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int main (void) {


    DIR *d = opendir (".");
    struct dirent *dir;

    if (d != NULL) {

        int files, directories = 0;

        while(dir=readdir(d))
            puts(dir->d_name);//Prints the actual names of the entries

        //Closing the directory
        (void) closedir (d);

    } else
        perror ("Couldn't open the directory");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "Doesn't work" means it crashes, prints out your password instead, or doesn't yield the (obviously correct) result? Anyway, try the macro `if (S_ISDIR(s.st_mode))` instead.

Comment: read the source code for `ls`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it. Here's my code for future references (if someone else needs that):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int main (void) {

    DIR *d = opendir (".");
    struct dirent *dir;

    if (d != NULL) {

        int files, directories = 0;

        while((dir=readdir(d)) != NULL) {

            if (dir->d_type == DT_REG)
                files++;
            if(dir->d_type == DT_DIR)
                directories++;
        }

        //Closing the directory
        (void) closedir (d);

        printf("%i Files and %i directories\n\n", files, directories);

    } else
        perror ("No such directory");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This increments `files`, but never increments `directories`.

Comment: I know. I added that later. It's just another if. But here. I'll add it in the code.